# How to deploy Java Web Start under Apache Karaf?

Tags: swing, java-web-start, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

One of our enterprise application is running over Apache Karaf , this application is accessed through web client.
We have another standalone desktop Java Swing based application. We want to invoke this application from browser.
So , we decided to deploy this application as Java Web Start and allow clients to invoke this application.

We have lot of examples how to deploy Java Web Start with tomcat like web servers.
But we want to deploy this in Apache Karaf . Anyone is having tutorial or notes for this?

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: @AndrewThompson , it is tough to recreate the application in web like using HTML/Javascript. What are the other options to launch a swing application from web?

Comment: *"What are the other options to launch a swing application from web?"* There are none. Unless you consider *"Download this jar and run it"* to fit that description.

Comment: As [mentioned on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start), Java Web Start is being phased out. See [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf) policy paper by Oracle. Nowadays you should be delivering your Swing/OpenJFX desktop app as a standalone executable that includes a Java runtime built with a tool like jlink. Users can download the app, or use an app store. If you really want a web app, consider using Vaadin rewrite the UI portion of your app while keeping existing business logic & backend code

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against Java Web Start.

If you don't want to rewrite the app, have a look at [webswing](https://www.webswing.org/). I have never used it but they claim they can convert Swing Apps to Web Apps instantly. I also have no idea how that would work with OSGi. Depends on what they actually do it may be easy or impossible.

If you are OK with some changes you can try [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) or [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/). Both are quite similar to Swing in terms of development style so it should be relatively easy to convert your app. Both can run inside OSGi container with some minor limitations and after some adjustments.